# $_POST doesn't work in String interpolation

Tags: php, post

I do not understand why the interpolation doesn't work.

This one works fine:

```
$usr_name = $_POST['usr_name']; 
echo  "<p>Your name is $usr_name </p>";
```

This one doesn't:

```
echo "<p>Your name is $_POST['usr_name'] </p>";
```

Comment: That would be [`echo "<p>Your name is {$_POST['usr_name']} </p>"`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), but you should not output user-input without [escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

Enclose arrays in `{}`:

```
echo "<p>Your name is {$_POST['usr_name']}</p>";
```

Comment: This is necessary for multidimentional arrays. In that case is better to remove the `'`

Comment: It works but that solution is more suited for multidimentional arrays, which can't inserted inside string either with `'` or without `'`, but only enclosing them in `{ }`

Comment: They should then probably note this on the manual page, because they have exactly this behaviour in one of their examples there: `// With one exception: braces surrounding arrays within strings allows constants
// to be interpreted
print "Hello {$arr[fruit]}";    // Hello carrot
print "Hello {$arr['fruit']}";  // Hello apple`

Answer (score -1):

Array keys inside the `" "` must be specified without the `' '`, as this:

```
 echo "<p>Your name is $_POST[usr_name] </p>";
```

From the [Official PHP's Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> // This will not work, and will result in a parse error, such as:
>
> // Parse error: parse error, expecting T_STRING' or T_VARIABLE' or
>   T_NUM_STRING'
>
> // This of course applies to using superglobals in strings as well
>
> print "Hello $arr['fruit']";
>
> print "Hello $_GET['foo']";

Alternatively, you can enclose it inside `{ }`, as do for multidimensional arrays:

```
echo "<p>Your name is {$_POST['usr_name']} </p>";
```

Comment: Did you downvote my answer and then include the same curly braces code I posted into your answer?

Comment: I simple completed my answer.

Comment: Omitting the quotes may work, but it is certainly not a "must" and should not be recommended - without the quotes, it is unclear if you're looking for `'usr_name'` or a constant named `usr_name` (in literally every other context, it's a constant lookup). What you've listed as an alternative is the correct answer - reduce it to that and I'll replace my downvote with an up one.